# How to merge 2 columns into one in LibreOffice or OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, merge

In my CSV, I have two columns which are really just one column, so I want to concatenate the content of these two columns - for each row - into the first one(after this I want to remove the extra column)? I use Mac, so I use LibreOffice and OpenOffice.

Comment: You can also paste the columns' contents into a plain text file and convert that to a table. See [this](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-paste-multiple-lines-in-a-writer-table-as-multiple-rows/19284).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I like to complicate things so here what I would do:

1. select both columns, right click, `Format Cells`, select `Text` format
2. right click first column and select `Insert Columns Left`
3. insert formula `=CONCATENATE(B2,C2)` (or whatever cells you need to concatenate) and pull down so the cells will fill with the correspondent concatenation
4. select the created first column and copy it
5. right click first column, select `Paste Special` and select `Text` under `Selection`, `None` under `Operations` and `Don't shift` under `Shift Cells` (remove all other selections). If warning appears just click `Yes` for overwriting the current cells
6. Now we have a column with the concatenated texts, so you can delete columns B and C (or whichever you have concatenated) and this will leave the concatenated text in first column (no formula there)

Comment: Thanks. Paste special was the thing I was missing. In the meanwhile I did the first part (steps 1, 2, 3, 4). If you just do paste, the formula stays, and if you delete the two initial columns, LibreOffice is confused (puts #REF or something, as a replacement for the result of the operation).

Comment: Confused :) Good one. It is not confused - it is just telling you that you are pointing to some non-existent content as you deleted the referenced values.

Comment: Yess, off course! :)

Answer (score 15):

The "standard" solution seems too much of a trouble for such a simple thing, so here is what I'll use :

1. Select and copy your columns.
2. Paste them into a text editor.
3. Use your editor "search and replace" function to convert tabulations into spaces.
4. Copy the result.
5. Paste it into your Gnumeric/LibreOffice/OpenOffice sheet, checking "fixed width".

Answer (score 2):

I did this like following way
In the column where you want to get the merged values write following.

```
=A2 & " " & B2
```

and drag to the end of column.

**Update:** added screenshot

Click on the cell, then hold from the right corner and drag.
[image]

Comment: Downvote. This was not asked. Making a third column and then cutting and pasting that into the first one while dropping the second is one more help column step. Merging was meant here as touching the two given columns only so that only the second column needs to be dropped. This is at least how I read it, else, the question would be too easy and the accepted answer too complicated to be so clearly upvoted.